# Simple product belonging to a configurable product not showing its details when clicking its thumbnail

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a simple product which belongs to a configurable product. The simple product is out of stock. But in the front-end it is showing is corresponding thumbnail. And on clicking that thumbnail, it is showing the details of next available simple product.

I want to show the correct details of that simple product. When I made the simple product it stock and quantity to 10, it is showing correctly. But without changing that I want to display the details of product. Even though I cannot add it to the cart.

I am using Magento **1.7.0.2**

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, you want to show the details of simple product? Where? How? If you can elaborate the scenario it would be helpful to solve your issue